# Dual boot wifi adaptor not detected (Windows 10 & Kali Linux)

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, dual-boot, iwlwifi

I recently installed Kali Linux on my PC, making it dual booting with Windows 10.  I have a 500GB m.2 Samsung 980 Pro SSD where I've installed Windows 10 and I have another 500GB Samsung EVO 860 SSD where I've installed Kali Linux.  I've installed Grub so when I turn on my computer, I have the option to pick Windows 10 or Kali.

If I pick Kali, I'm getting the following error before the login screen:

[image]

I'm able to login to Kali, however, if the above error shows, Kali is not able to detect my wifi adapter (Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200).

HOWEVER, If I first boot into Windows 10, restart the PC, then boot into Kali, I get the following different set of errors, and wifi connects automatically and everything works.

[image]

I've tried this many times and the pattern is: if I want wifi to work in Kali, I'll need to boot into windows first then kali. Otherwise, if I boot straight into Kali, wifi adapter will not be found and wifi will not work.

How do I fix this wifi issue?

Hardware specs:

- Gigabyte B550I Aorus Pro AX
- AMD Ryzen 5 5600x
- Samsung 980 Pro 500GB NVMe (Windows 10 installed)
- Samsung 860 EVO 500GB SSD (Kali Linux installed)
- Nvidia RTX3080 FE
- Crucial Ballistix 32 GB (2 x 16 GB) DDR4-3200

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post images if you can get that information from the log files (check `/var/log/kern.log` or similar).

Comment: @Eduardo thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to disable Windows `Fast Boot` and see if it works.

> If you have a dual-boot machine with a recent version of Windows and
> start seeing problems during initialization of the WiFi device when
> booting Linux, the problem could be due to the “fast startup” feature
> on Windows.

From [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled).

Comment: Glad it helped. Do you know why I didn't get the bounty?

Answer (score 0):

Download the wifi driver `iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0.tgz` from [Intel website](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) then extract to `/lib/firmware` directory.

[Firmware during the installation](https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware#Firmware_during_the_installation)

> You can also download the firmware archive for your platform and unpack it into a directory named `firmware` in the root of a removable storage device (USB/CD drive).
> ...

> When the installer starts, it will automatically find the firmware files in the directory on the removable storage and, if needed, install the required firmware.